# What is the right word for this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> "I'm just remembering how ... I am about this guy"

I don't know what to say. I need a word that describes either when you don't know what you think about a person or when what you think about the person changes.

Comment: *ambivalent*...

Comment: unsure, not confident, not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps **uncertain** will work for you.

> #### Uncertain
>
> *adjective*
>
> 1. (of a person) not completely confident or sure of something.
>    ***‘An uncertain future’***
> 2. Not able to be relied on; not known or definite.
>    ***‘I was uncertain how to proceed’***

([OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/uncertain))

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you're looking for is **undecided**. According to the Oxford Living Dictionaries,

**[undecided](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/undecided)**

> 1. (of a person) not having made a decision:
>      ‘the jury remained undecided’
> 2. Not settled or resolved:
>      ‘the match was still undecided’

Answer (score 0):

Unsure

Definition of unsure as per Merriam Webster dictionary is  : not feeling sure about the truth, wisdom, or trustworthiness of someone or something

or

Irresolute

Definition of irresolute as per Merriam Webster dictionary is   :  uncertain how to act or proceed

The word "ambivalent" is an option too

Definition of ambivalent

```
1
:  simultaneous and contradictory attitudes or feelings (as attraction and repulsion) toward an object, person, or action

2
a :  continual fluctuation (as between one thing and its opposite) b :  uncertainty as to which approach to follow
```